How to Send SMS Directly Using React Native Expo Without Redirecting to Default Messaging App?
I tried using the expo-sms library, but it redirects SMS to the default messaging app on Android. How can I send a direct message using a React Native Expo app?
Here is the code that I have already checked:
import * as SMS from 'expo-sms';

const sendSMS = async () => {
  const contactNumbers = data.data
    .filter(item => item.phone.length == 10 || item.phone.length == 9)
    .map(item => item.phone);
  console.log(contactNumbers);

  const isAvailable = await SMS.isAvailableAsync();
  if (isAvailable) {
    const { result } = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(
      contactNumbers,
      message
    );
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    ToastAndroid.show('SMS service is not available on this device', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    console.log('SMS service is not available on this device');
  }
};


Directing sending SMS using react native expo


In iOS you cannot, in Android if an application is the default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler you can: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888170.
